# How to adjust Model for rare binary outcome with Tensorflow or GBM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, xgboost, gbm

I'm currently working on data with rare binary outcome, i.e. the response vector contains mostly 0 and only a few 1 (approximately 1.5% ones). I've got about 20 continuous explanatory variables. I tried to train models using GBM, Random Forests, TensorFlow with Keras backend.

I observed a special behavior of the models, regardless which method I used:

The accuracy is high (~98%) but the model predicts probabilities for class "0" for all outcomes as ~98.5% and for class "1" ~1,5%.

How can I prevent this behavior?

I'm using RStudio. For Example a TF model with Keras would be:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(20)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "sigmoid")

parallel_model <- multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
parallel_model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "adam",             
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = "binary_accuracy")

histroy <- parallel_model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  batch_size = 64,
  epochs = 100,
  class_weight = list("0"=1,"1"=70),
  verbose = 1,
  validation_split = 0.2
)
```

But my observation is not limited to TF. This makes my question more general. I'm not asking for specific adjustments for the model above, rather I'd like to discuss at what point all outcomes are assigned the same probability.

I can guess, the issue is connected to the loss-function.
I know there is no way to use AUC as loss functions, since it's not differentiable. If I test models with AUC with unknown data, the result is not better than random guessing.

I don't mind answers with code in Python, since this isn't a problem about coding rather than general behavior and algorithms.

Comment: I see you have two classes, and each can have values 0 or 1. I'm not sure if the class weights are considering things correctly. Question: is it possible to have "both classes" as correct in a sample? Or is it a strictly categorical problem (only one of the classes is correct).

Comment: @DanielMöller the outcome is either 0 or 1. Never can happen 1,1 or 0,0. I never thought about this. How will this affect the model?

Comment: So,  my answer below is the way. The most important there is having a big batch size (I'd say >200) and using a proper metric.

Answer (score 1):

When your problem has unbalanced classes, I suggest using SMOTE (on the training data only!!! never use smote on your testing data!!!) before training the model.

For example:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
X_trn_balanced, Y_trn_balanced = SMOTE(random_state=1, ratio=1).fit_sample(X_trn, Y_trn)
#next fit the model with the balanced data
model.fit(X_trn_balanced, Y_trn_balanced )
```

Answer (score 1):

In my (not so big) experience with AUC problems and rare positives, I see models with one class (not two). It's either "result is positive (1)" or "result is negative (0)".

Metrics like accuracy are useless for these problems, you should use AUC based metrics with big batch sizes.

For these problems, it doesn't matter whether the outcome probabilities are too little, as long as there is a difference between them. (Forests, GBM, etc. will indeed output these little values, but this is not a problem)

For neural networks, you can try to use class weights to increase the output probabilities. But notice that if you split the result in two separate classes (considering only one class should be positive), it doesn't matter if you use weights, because:

- For the first class, low weights: predict all ones is good
- For the second class, high weights: predict all zeros is good (weighted to very good)

So, as an initial solution, you can:

- Use a `'softmax'` activation (to guarantee your model will have only one correct output) and a `'categorical_crossentropy'` loss.
- (Or, preferrably) Use a model with only one class and keep `'sigmoid'` with `'binary_crossentropy'`.

I always work with the preferrable option above. In this case, if you use batch sizes that are big enough to contain one or two positive examples (batch size around 100 for you), weights may even be discarded. If the batch sizes are too little and many batches don't contain positive results, you may have too many weight updates towards plain zeros, which is bad.

You may also resample your data and, for instance, multiply by 10 the number of positive examples, so your batches contain more positives and training becomes easier.

### Example of AUC metric to determine when training should end:

```
#in python - considering outputs with only one class
def aucMetric(true, pred):
    true= K.flatten(true)
    pred = K.flatten(pred)

    totalCount = K.shape(true)[0]

    values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(pred, k = totalCount)        
    sortedTrue = K.gather(true, indices)

    tpCurve = K.cumsum(sortedTrue)
    negatives = 1 - sortedTrue
    auc = K.sum(tpCurve * negatives)

    totalCount = K.cast(totalCount, K.floatx())
    positiveCount = K.sum(true)
    negativeCount = totalCount - positiveCount
    totalArea = positiveCount * negativeCount
    return  auc / totalArea
```